# The type of auto

Tags: c++11

I'm really curious- why does `auto` favour value types? Surely it would be better for `auto` to be what `auto&&` is now- a reference which extends the lifetime of temporaries if necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Why" questions like this are difficult (if not impossible) to answer -- even the committee members involved may easily have difficulty reconstructing the entire sequence of events that led to the decision they made.

That leads to the second point: such decisions often happen due as much to a sequence of events, as to the single "static" overall view you get from looking at the FDIS (or any other draft of the standard).

Despite the problems, you can get at least some more idea of how the decisions came about by reading proposals, counter-proposals, arguments, etc., that lead up to them. In this case, the proposal history runs something like this:

[N1478](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf) *Decltype and auto*
[N1527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1527.pdf) *Mechanisms for querying types of expressions:
Decltype and auto revisited*
[N1607](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1607.pdf) *Decltype and auto (revision 3)*
[N1705](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1705.pdf) *Decltype and auto (revision 4)*
[N1721](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1721.pdf) *Deducing the type of variable from its initializer expression*
[N1737](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1737.pdf) *A Proposal to Restore Multi-declarator* auto *Declarations*
[N1794](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1794.pdf) *Deducing the type of variable from its initializer expression (revision 2)*
[N1894](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1894.pdf) *Deducing the type of variable from its initializer expression (revision 3)*
[N1978](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1978.pdf) *Decltype (revision 5)*
[N1984](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1984.pdf) **Deducing the type of variable from its initializer expression (revision 4)*
[N2115](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2115.pdf) *Decltype (revision 6): Proposed Wording*
[N2337](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2007/n2337.pdf) *The syntax of* auto *declarations*
[N2343](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2343.pdf) *Decltype (revision 7): Proposed Wording*
[N2763](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2763.htm) *Unified Function Syntax*
[N2825](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2825.html) *Unified Function Syntax* (revision)

The proposals for `decltype` and `auto` were bifurcated around 2005, but I've included later `dectype` papers as well, since both deal with similar issues, and they (seem to have) tried to maintain coherency between the two.

It's not a proposal for the standard, but there's also [*Representing C++ Directly, Completely and Efficiently*](http://parasol.tamu.edu/pivot/publications/cxx-rep-short.pdf)  by Gabriel Dos Reis and Bjarne Stroustrup, which has some bearing on the same subject, and probably did at least a little to shape thinking on the subject.

There are undoubtedly at least a few more papers I've missed here (at least some of the rvalue reference papers are probably relevant), but these should at least be a reasonable start toward understanding how things got the way they are.